# contract methods undefined

Tags: web3js, javascript

I am quite new with javascript web3 so don't be judge too hard.

I am using web3 version 1.0.0 beta.

I am taking the web3 reference this way:

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // If a web3 instance is already provided by Meta Mask.
    web3Provider = web3.currentProvider;
    web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
    // Specify default instance if no web3 instance provided
    web3Provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/1b07b6c661304ef48005e16b43b7efa9');
    web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);
}
```

And then i am trying to get the contract reference:

```
var abi = [...];

console.log(abi);

var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi, "0x2a2a7c53a6cc3d775e80c38d0fc446e73078902f");




myContract.methods.getPoll(1)
.call({from:localAccount}, function(error, result){
    console.log('error: ' + error);
    console.log(result);
})
```

The error is:  Cannot read property 'getPoll' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't creating the contract object correctly. What version of Web3.js are you using? 1.0 or 0.2.x? Here is how you do it for each:

1.0: `var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0x2a2a7c53a6cc3d775e80c38d0fc446e73078902f")`

0.2.x: `var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at("0x2a2a7c53a6cc3d775e80c38d0fc446e73078902f")`

I highly suggest you use 1.0 if you aren't yet, even though it's in beta.

Comment: I tried this "
  var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at("0x2a2a7c53a6cc3d775e80c38d0fc446e73078902f");" and i get the same error.

Comment: And about the version, i think it is 1.0.0 beta. I am importing it this way: "<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.36/dist/web3.min.js" integrity="sha256-nWBTbvxhJgjslRyuAKJHK+XcZPlCnmIAAMixz6EefVk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>"

Comment: That's not what I put though. Try what I put in my answer,  `var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, "0x2a2a7c53a6cc3d775e80c38d0fc446e73078902f")` Glad to hear you're using 1.0 though!

Comment: I made it work, apparently web3 version was 0.2.x taken from metamask. Now that i am using 1.0.0 it works. At least that part...

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
web3.eth.contract
```

To this:

```
new web3.eth.Contract
```

Comment: “Web3.eth.Contract is not a constructor” or something similar

Comment: @AlexandruSandu: `web3`, not `Web3`!

Comment: I know, i tried that but i wrote this comment form my phone and misspelled it

Answer (score 0):

You must write it in this form:

if `getPoll` method is `view` or `pure`:

```
myContract.methods.getPoll(1).call(option,function(error,result){
    if (! error)
        console.log(expand(result));
    else
        console.log(error);
});
```

and if the method is changing the state variables use `send` method, instead of `call`.

`option` is a variable that clarify the transaction specifications, like:

```
var option = {from: 0x...};
```

Comment: Still undefined

Comment: Is your ABI code correct?

Comment: Yes, i am using the same json with the truffle-contract method of getting the contract, which works fine (“$.getJSON(yadayadayada)”)